# How to change source of audio in an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I'm trying to write a browser add-on which adds additional functionality to an existing website. Right now on the website, sounds are played when certain things happen (new message, new game, etc.)

I want to modify the sound that plays when these events happen. The sounds are created and kept in an anonymous JavaScript function and they are never added to the page in the form of an audio tag, therefore I cannot select them with jQuery and change the audio source.

When I use the profiler in firebug I can see calls being made to the anonymous function, but I just have no idea how I can substitute my own sounds.

I thought that it might be possible to have a function fire on an audio start event which checks the source url to see what sound to play, plays my custom sound, and cancels the play function. The problem is I have no clue how to do this.

Here is an example of what I see in the profiler when the sound is being played: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4GFF.png

**To make my question more clear: is there some way to trigger an event when ANY audio is being played? Even from inside anonymous functions?**